# Encryption Strategy for Flashing or updating firmware on ARM Cortex M0+

Tags: c, encryption, arm, embedded, can-bus

I want to flash a firmware update through CAN, on my ARM Cortex M0+ MCU. I'm using MKV11 microcontroller.

How can I secure the firmware, so that, even if the transfer(from PC to MCU) is sniffed, it will be secure?

Memory requirement is also a constraint for me, but right now, I am open to all suggestions.

Also, should I go for some library, or develop bare-metal code for Cryptographic Algorithms?

Comment: *Assuming* the MCU has a protection from reading the firmware back, you will need to have a permanently flashed bootloader capable of decrypting and flashing the main firmware. This way you can transfer the firmware while it is encrypted. But of course, you need to do a detailed threat model in order to cover all of the considered cases.

Comment: Yes @EugeneSh. ,this want I am leaning towards. The bootloader will also contain the "intelligence" to decrypt the Firmware. So what encryption strategy(bare-metal C Code)/algorithm/library can I use to complete my objective?
Also, can you briefly explain what does "threat model" mean? Or could you tell me some resource?

Comment: Encrypt/decrypt the whole chunk of data then have CAN act as a mere carrier. But security on CAN bus systems often doesn't make sense - most of the time they should be protected by the usual anti-burglar measures. Unless some IoT person decided to allow wireless firmware updates of sensitive MCUs - then the fix is to remove the IoT person from the project.

Comment: There are several things to consider. a) Security Access before you allow to disclose the transfer services, e.g. by public/private key. b) you could encrypt/decrypt the data by something like AES-128 which is fast. Some MCUs even have now hardware support for this (aka EVITA, CSE, HSM). Not sure about though for your MCU. Just for reference, run exclusively on an NXP e200z7 core @240MHz, RSA2k key+signature verification took like 180ms in SW.

Comment: @kesselhaus I must do everything through software only. can you please give me some way, or library that i may use to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

A small book could be written on the topics you touch in this question.  But this site isn't intended to be a consulting service or a blog entry site, so I'll try to answer your question succinctly.  Here I can't (won't) address all your nuances such as memory constraints, CAN-bus-specific stuff, securing the contents inside the MCU -- way too much to address.

For your firmware update to be secure, it must be **encrypted** and **authenticated**.  Either alone won't be sufficient.  Use symmetric-key cryptography to encrypt, and public-key cryptography (e.g. RSA or elliptic curve) to authenticate via digital signature.

You should use accepted cryptographic primitives (e.g. AES-256 and ECDSA) instead of rolling your own.  And you shouldn't implement (code) your own crypto, use a validated library (too many to name / recommend here).

Comment: Can you explain why it needs to be encrypted?  Surely the code isn't a secret?  (OTOH, the authentication can be very important, since you need to ensure the device will not accept malicious code).

Comment: Of course it doesn't help that OP hasn't presented the threat model - you can't even start an outline design before that's in place!

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to architect your firmware to implement the bootloader with a crypto function. Communication must be private that is the CAN data must be encrypted for one thing. But before you can even start downloading encrypted image payload, your MCU must be able to authenticate its communication partner. In symmetric authentication, the MCU must send a random challenge to the CAN node. The CAN node encrypts it with its key (eg. AES-256) and returns the digest which your MCU must compare against after it encrypts the challenge with the same key.
Once authenticated, the CAN node can begin sending payload messages which are encrypted with the same or different key. These will likely be chained together and accompanied by a random challenge to make each frame unique.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).